# junit test when a method is called from one test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

```
public void createRootElement() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("/home/asdf/Desktop/test.properties"));
        File file = new File(prop.getProperty("filefromroot"));
        try
            {
                // if file doesn't exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists())
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write("<root>"); //create the root tag for the XML File.
                bw.close();
            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            writeLog(e.getMessage(),false);
            }
    }
```

I'm new to junit testing.I would like to know how to write test case for this and what all to be considered. how to call the method is called from this test.?

Comment: this should get you started: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JUnit Test Case should look like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ClassToBeTested c = new ClassToBeTested();
        c.createRootElement();
        assertTrue(c.rootElementExists());
    }

}
```

You mark the test method with the @Test annotation and write the code that executes what you want to test.

At this example, I created a instance of your class and called the createRootElement method.

After that, I made a assertion to verify if everything behaved like I expected.

There are many things you can assert. Read the JUnit documentation for more information.

A good practice is to write the test BEFORE you actually write the code. So the test will guide you on how to write a better code. This is called TDD. Google for it.